# Regex company name cleanup simplify

Tags: regex

Hi I am new to regex and I am trying to use this to clean up some company names in our data.

I have been trying to write the regex but I believe there is a simpler way than my code so I am here to seek for your expertise.

My regex is as below. It's done in C# but I believe its similar across other programming langauges.

```
Regex.Replace("IBM AUSTRALIA PTY LTD","(\\sPTY(\\.)?\\sLTD(\\.)?)$|\\sPTY(\\.)?$|\\s(LTD|LIMITED)(\\.)?","")
```

I would like the expression to replace PTY , PTY., LTD, LTD. LIMTED etc with empty space. If I can get a way around from writing the repetitive code like I did, I think I could do something similar to get rid of AUS, AUST, AUSTRALIA.

Or is it possible if I could do match \sAUS(TRALIA)?\s and replace it with empty space.

All below name should return IBM.

```
IBM AUS LTD
IBM AUST LTD
IBM AUSTRALIA
IBM AUSTRALIA LIMITED
IBM AUSTRALIA LTD
IBM AUSTRALIA PTY LTD
```

Thanks !

Comment: Try `(^\w+)( ?.*)` for your regex and replace with `\1`.  Not entirely sure if that's what you're look for.  Have a look [at the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/nL0cP0/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try, `(\s(AUS)(T|RALIA)*)(\sPTY)?(\s(LTD|LIMITED))?` replace with emty char. I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following regex with multiline and global mode:

```
.+(?= AUS)(.*)
```

Eat up as many charachters as possible(min one) before the position of `" AUS"` with positive lookahead and take all till the end in capture group 1.